# Как объединить два скрипта в один

Tags: php, json

Дано два скрипта к которым обращается javascript код клиента:

file1.php

```
$data = stripslashes(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$get_data = json_decode($data);

$value1 = $get_data->{'part_no'};
```

file2.php

```
$data = stripslashes(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$get_data = json_decode($data);

$value2 = $get_data->{'item_no'};
```

Вопрос: Какие "лучшие практики" существуют чтобы объединить эти два файла в один. Т.е. выяснять какой объект пришел и кудато перенапрвлять дальше.

Первое что приходит на ум это что-то типа:
*При помощи условий выяснять содержится ли имя ключа в пришедшем объекте и в соответствии с результатом отправлять дальше...*

Comment: Роутер нужен. Регистрируешь роуты, потом матчишь текущий роут(method, uri, параметры) на зареганные роуты. Ну и средствами веб-сервера шлёшь все роуты на одну точку входа(mod_rewrite/location). Можно подглядеть, как это выглядит во фреймворках(laravel, symfony и т.п.)

Comment: А вообще учи MVC, дополнение к комментарию выше

Comment: Человек спросил как сделать единую точку входа а ему про паттерны начали задвигать (которой вообще не видели а не слышали).. забавно))
тс, правильно вам @vp_arth ответил

Comment: мне кажется ваше предположение правильное, я бы добавил поле в данные которые отправляются, например, $method, $path, $route, $type и отправлял бы в нём нужную вам метку в зависимости откуда сделали запрос, дальше как вы написали обрабатывал эту метку и в зависимости какая она, выполнял дальше манипуляции

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы создать единую точку входа, сначала тебе надо настроить сервер, чтобы он все запросы к файлам, которых не существует, перенаправлял на твой php-файл, который будет являться точкой входа в приложение. У каждого сервера свои способы как это сделать. Так ты сможешь обращаться к статике (css, js, картинки) без участия php-кода, и сможешь обрабатывать все запросы к динамической части приложения из одного места.

Для роутинга советую воспользоваться готовым пакетом, чтобы не строить велосипед, учитывая методы запросов, параметры в URL, заголовок Accept и другие вещи, которые уже учитаны в готовых пакетах. Например есть хороший пакет [от Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/routing).

Если же хочется во всем разобраться самому, то тебе нужно смотреть на суперглобальную переменную `$_SERVER`, в котором скорее всего будет лежать параметр `REQUEST_URI`. Этот параметр стоит проверить на матчинг с паттерном твоего ресурса, и совершать нужные вещи в зависимости от пришедшего запроса. Не забудь про [методы запроса](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods).

Почитай про [REST](https://habr.com/ru/post/38730/).

И может быть посмотри в сторону готовых фреймворков (Laravel, Symfony, Yii), они дают большую базу готовых инструментов и помогают держаться в рамках стандартов разработки.

Answer (score 1):

file.php

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$get_data = json_decode($data);
$value1 = $get_data->part_no ?? null;
$value2 = $get_data->item_no ?? null;
```